# Parsing out data from one variable using complex rules in R

Tags: r, parsing

I am importing data into R from another source (i.e., I cannot easily change the in-coming format/values).

Among the variables is one that include one or more of these possible values:

- Mother (biological mother, foster mother, step mother, etc.)
- Father (biological father, foster father, step father, etc.)
- Grandparent(s) (biological, foster, step, etc.)
- Brother(s) older than 18
- Sister(s) older than 18
- Other adults (aunts, uncles, etc.)

all within the same "cell" so that possible data look like:

**Sample Input Data Frame (df)**

```
df <- read.table(text =
"row lives.with.whom
  1  'Mother (biological mother, foster mother, step mother, etc.), Father (biological father, foster father, step father, etc.), Grandparent(s) (biological, foster, step, etc.), Brother(s) older than 18, Sister(s) older than 18, Other adults (aunts, uncles, etc.)'
  2  ''
  3  'Mother (biological mother, foster mother, step mother, etc.), Sister(s) older than 18'
  4  'Mother (biological mother, foster mother, step mother, etc.), Father (biological father, foster father, step father, etc.)'", header = T)
```

Within `R`, how could I efficiently create rules to parse out these responses into separate columns, one column for each type of family member, so that the output would look like this:

**Sample Output Data Frame**

```
mother <- c(1,0,1,1)
father <- c(1,0,0,1)
adult.brother <- c(1,0,0,0)
adult.sister <- c(1,0,1,0)
grandparent <- c(1,0,0,0)
other.adult <- c(1,0,0,0)
output.df <- cbind(mother, father, adult.brother, adult.sister, grandparent, other.adult)
colnames(output.df) <- c("Mother", "Father", "Brother", "Sister", "Grandparent", "Other adult")
output.df

     Mother Father Brother Sister Grandparent Other adult
[1,]      1      1       1      1           1           1
[2,]      0      0       0      0           0           0
[3,]      1      0       0      1           0           0
[4,]      1      1       0      0           0           0
```

Comment: This is easy to do and best demonstrated using specific sample data. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51814298/edit) your post to include representative and copy&paste-able sample data.

Comment: No follow-up after 2 hours and no update means a down-vote from me (will remove if you edit/revise your question). Generally we expect you to hang around after posting a question to respond to any questions/comments. I can see that you've been checking SO on and off over the last 2 hours, so if you like to get help please spend some time adding critical information to your post.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I've edited it to try to make it clearer.

Comment: Much better (down-vote removed); I've added a solution below that should get you started; please take a look.

Comment: Wonderful! `tidyverse` is works wonderfully (after installing dependencies like `libcurl4` in Ubuntu and a learning curve). I'll further abuse my noob status to heartily thank both you and @Suhas for the help and the warm welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Great, glad it worked out. Welcome to SO and do stick around:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` option that should get you started

```
library(tidyverse)
rel <- list("Mother", "Father", "Brother", "Sister", "Grandparent", "Other adult")
names(rel) <- unlist(rel)
bind_cols(df[, 1, drop = F], map(rel, ~+str_detect(tolower(df[, 2]), tolower(.x))))
#  row Mother Father Brother Sister Grandparent Other adult
#1   1      1      1       1      1           1           1
#2   2      0      0       0      0           0           0
#3   3      1      0       0      1           0           0
#4   4      1      1       0      0           0           0
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "row lives.with.whom
  1  'Mother (biological mother, foster mother, step mother, etc.), Father (biological father, foster father, step father, etc.), Grandparent(s) (biological, foster, step, etc.), Brother(s) older than 18, Sister(s) older than 18, Other adults (aunts, uncles, etc.)'
  2  ''
  3  'Mother (biological mother, foster mother, step mother, etc.), Sister(s) older than 18'
  4  'Mother (biological mother, foster mother, step mother, etc.), Father (biological father, foster father, step father, etc.)'", header = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

I made some assumptions and tried to solve it.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
# create nested lists with names of mothers and fathers for two ppl
mother <- list(list("bio_1","step_1","foster_1"), list("bio_2", "stp_2", "foster_2"))
father <- list(list("bio_1", "foster_1", "other_1"), list("bio_2", "stp_2", "foster_2"))

# convert to data frame
test_object <- data_frame(person = c(1,2),mother,father)

# print 
test_object

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  person mother     father    
   <dbl> <list>     <list>    
1      1 <list [3]> <list [3]>
2      2 <list [3]> <list [3]>

# first unnest the lists and get to the inner list
# then convert from wide to long form data
# do another unnnest to get the actual data in the long format
test_object %>%
  unnest(.) %>%
    gather(data = ., key = relationship, value = name, -person) %>%
      unnest() -> test_object
    
    test_object
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   person relationship name    
    <dbl> <chr>        <chr>   
 1      1 mother       bio_1   
 2      1 mother       step_1  
 3      1 mother       foster_1
 4      2 mother       bio_2   
 5      2 mother       stp_2   
 6      2 mother       foster_2
 7      1 father       bio_1   
 8      1 father       foster_1
 9      1 father       other_1 
10      2 father       bio_2   
11      2 father       stp_2   
12      2 father       foster_2
```

Here are links to [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org) and [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki) that contain a lot packages and functions to solve most of your data-carpentry/wrangling issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
rel<-list("Mother", "Father", "Brother", "Sister", "Grandparent", "Other adult")

for(i in 1:6){
  df$i<-if_else(grepl(rel[[i]],df$lives.with.whom),1,0)
  colnames(df)[i+2]<-rel[[i]]
}
```